# my apache2 is running in port 80 but it doesnt serving files

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, port80

So I have my apache running at port 80.

My ip is http://159.203.209.68/ but it is not serving file. Initially I was able to run app at different port i.e 8079. So I killed docker proxy running at port 80 and then purged apache2 and reinstalled. Now its not serving file. Please help me solve this.

> netstat -anp | grep apache tcp6       0      0 :::80
>   :::*                    LISTEN      18128/apache2

Comment: Could you explain a little bit? You want to run apache2 on your host machine or inside of the docker container?

Comment: im runnng on my host machine

Comment: You should check the log file - usually it's /var/log/apache2/error.log